# Removing line breaks with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, line-breaks

I got a little problem here.

The thing is that in my database I got a text, and then I print it onto the screen and the code goes like:

```
<p>Text 1</p>
<p>Text 2</p>
```

Thats the output in HTML cause I use tinyMCE plugin. Goes well so far. The thing is, that I want to put it into a javascript variable (like: `onclick="my_function(the_text_above)")`, but the output code makes a linebreak and that goes into an illegal token when the function runs.

Hope you can lend me a hand with this issue I encountered.

Comment: thanks, that preg_replace helped and now works properly!

Answer (score 1):

You just replace /n (new line) with nothing

PHP

```
echo str_replace("\n","","your \n text");
```

Javascript

```
"Your \ntext".split("\n").join("")
```

Comment: thanks you too, used the preg_replace that I found in the possible duplication of post that can be found at the top. thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_encode` for that.

It will look like:

```
var jsVariable = <?php echo json_encode($stringFromDb); ?>;
```

`json_encode` will produce legal js literal regardless of input.

PS: it makes no sense to remove lines if what you need is just to sanitize the data properly.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to strip the line breaks from your string. You can use str_replace to do that.

```
str_replace("\n",'');
```

this will remove UNIX breaks from your string. I don't know which type of break your code contain, so \n might not work right away. another one is "\r" and I think there's few others, I sadly don't know them all.

Comment: thanks, I already used preg_replace instead, but thanks for that!